# Help me understand matrix manipulation; calculus on manifolds

Tags: matrices, manifolds

In a proof, the step goes from
$$\left| \begin{bmatrix}x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta\\-x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta\end{bmatrix} \right|^2     
 = (x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)^2 + (-x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta)^2$$
How does this equality hold?

Comment: This is just an application of the definition of the norm (length) of a vector.

Comment: @amd wait, so a matrix is a vector?

Comment: Where do you see a matrix? You have a 2x1 column vector.

Comment: Try using `\cos` and `\sin` for operators, it makes them render much nicer, e.g. $sin\;\sin$

Comment: In this case you're looking at a $2×1$ column vector. That being said, matrices are indeed vectors. When we look at the definition of a vector space, we see that it consists of a field $F$ of scalars, a set $V$ of objects (which we'll call vectors) and two operations. - 1) Addition such that addition is commutative and associative, $∃!0$ in $V$, and negative counterparts exist. - 2) Scalar multiplication such that if $a,b∈V:1a=a,c_1c_2a=c_1(c2_a),c(a+b)=ca+cb,(c_1+c_2)a=c_1a+c_2a$. This is a lot of information for now, but you can see it all holds for matrices too. **Edit:** fixed a typo.